# evernote updating note resources

Tags: python, evernote

I'm using the Evernote API for Python to create an app that allows the user to create and update notes, but I'm having trouble understanding how to efficiently update Evernote resources. This mainly occurs when I'm converting from HTML to ENML (Evernote Markup Language), where I'm creating resources from img tags (right now I'm only considering image resources).

My question is this: how can I tell, given HTML, if a note's resources needs to be updated? I've considered comparing the image data to all of the current resources' data, but that seems really slow. Right now I just make a new resource for each img tag.

Some helpful resources I've found include the [Evernote resources guide](http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php) and [this sample code in the Evernote SDK](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-python/blob/master/sample/client/EDAMTest.py). Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: maybe hashing the html and determining a diff is your solution? http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/49550/which-hashing-algorithm-is-best-for-uniqueness-and-speed

Comment: that's possible, but then I would need to hash the image data for comparison every time I get the HTML, which still seems expensive

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be a comparison of the MD5 hash of the file.  Evernote notes track resources by their MD5 hash.

To see the MD5 hash of the file attached to an Evernote note, just look at the ENML elements labeled "en-media", the form of the tags can be seen below:

```
 <en-media type="mime-type" hash="md5-of-file" />
```

Where `mime-type` is the file type and `md5-of-file` is the MD5 hash of the file.  To get the ENML of a note call getNote (documentation here) and make sure to specify you want the contents.  The ENML contents of the note is the value of the `content` attribute of the object that is returned by getNote ([a note object](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Note)).

While hashes can be expensive MD5 is relatively quick and it will be quicker to compute the MD5 hash of a file than it will be to wait for the network to download images.

Also, the [updateResource method documentation](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_updateResource) says:

> "Submit a set of changes to a resource to the service. This can be
>   used to update the meta-data about the resource, but **cannot be used to
>   change the binary contents of the resource (including the length and
>   hash)**. These cannot be changed directly without creating a new
>   resource and removing the old one via updateNote."

So the *only* way to "update" a resource is to remove the old resource from the note and create a new one in its place.  You can do this by removing the resource by remove the [Resource Object](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/Types.html#Struct_Resource) from the list contained in the resources attribute of the note in question.  To add a new note simple add a new resource object to the same list.